# Modify and add to netcdf attributes

Tags: netcdf

I have a netCDF file with the foll. information on one of the dimensions:

```
int time(time=100);
  :units = "calendar_year as %Y";
  :_ChunkSizes = 1048576; // int
```

Are there any tools available e.g. nco that can modify the attributes like so:

```
int time(time=100);
   :units = "year as %Y.%f" ;
   :calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
   :_ChunkSizes = 1048576; // int
```

Comment: There sure is: http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncatted-netCDF-Attribute-Editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user308827 is right...

```
ncatted -a 'units,time,o,c,"year as %Y.%f"' -a 'calendar,time,o,c,"proleptic_gregorian"' in.nc out.nc
```